# Puzzle. Txt file with encoded text. How to decode?

Tags: text, decode, puzzle, encode

I have a text file, that contains 50,000 lines of "strange" text:

```
UEsDBBQAAgAIACaOVEA6e5H83pcBAMLBAQArAAAAW1NhbXN1
bmddIC0gVGVzdCB0YXNrIC0gU291bmQgZGVjcnlwdG9yLnBu
Z+z9ZVBcXdcFiia4B/cgTQPBJTgEC9bBEtwCBCe4uwVtNN24
QyAQ3C24OwR3d3e303zv++T57vl5761zbt06VV3V1bLWXjLX
mGOuNcfe4I8K0phopGgvXrzABMlIKL14AY/x4gUCKQoc7Jsv
3GZA2NtLByVp8RfFQ+Q7sA8IpmLyYi9elEWh339BhH2mMpRR
kn/xwp3uxQvfgBcvbmFf+W6/eOHE/uLFrv6LFwIJL14Q2ab8
/iT04sVTJEhCTMVVdz8VMUW18+6JF1Rfv2fh4uISpoGCAsUN
pWIMRfz169f0L99Rmdw3aDKaMWgoxCFFGT8qD5+8rkZuBp86
FupLdS4PvYcs9GwP5/nfDjfkCm8l1m0ZEeHjG+1gv8T5+0LB
FgX+n77owcX59yO2H/tLMLAK7d9vQqioINkm1HAAqv++cEFf
4f9+AHwnfekGVVrL1vj71Ua4r4QSf4EtgTqChOj/vKi4YYXy
7JSY/17EXkoUkJeiWhvK9L/qAWeP8zHEoYT4/s9LlJ+GCqIy
xKjTSfBPU2QiYDV/TcGX/afijBSc7zKMpgTFq6G+/y2XDauZ
gVshlPafij8OocgAYyvQ1O0kRf9bTglWcwwpfSfuPxW/MUUA
Qvs0Awtq//YiD1bzh4hoA/A/Fce8hXVio7BNVedvL8ZhNf/s
ApVJ/FNxHwmsE/ZqK4zFf3vxFVbz/+fD8yTi1xn2lPDWdMXj
aJBUyKivv6TB6wn+wcb89pRA3VHgoTL3cu4IsuDiw8dbIql2
OAhu3teuKD/s6/tNbwcd215q3qfT1GRBa7+hgaNMJkjDnoY2
98VqH9VtwdOnXV9j8jaMXzY1vfNoFHTaNZWNu/90uycGyDuf
gjDj/7dJuDSlnjd9/BVEjSM2u2OKkdaT6xN7xTue
```

And at this moment, I don't know how to process this text. Effectively it reads like puzzle text.

What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Base64 encoding of a PNG file called Sound decryptor.png.

Use any Base64 decoder to convert it to a file... Such as this one: http://download.cnet.com/Base64-Encoder-Decoder/3000-10250_4-10555647.html

Comment: This is not a PNG file, this is a PKZIP archive containing one (maybe others as well), called "[Samsung] - Test task - Sound decryptor.png". One would never know the file name unless its container provided some metadata (i.e. filename) about it.

Comment: yes, it is archive, that contains 1 png file and 4 wav file. I use base64 decoder to convert fo zip file and after open with 7-zip.

Answer (score 1):

This is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded data.

The particular snippet in your question looks like the beginning of a ZIP-file (begins with the typical `PK`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a base64-encoded ZIP archive, here's the start of it: `PK...T@:{‘...[Samsung] - Test task - Sound decryptor.png....` (contains a PNG image, perhaps something else).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded text. Depending on the programming language you use, you should be able to find a function to decode it for you.

For [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), use `base64.b64decode(text)`. For [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), use `base64_decode($text)`. Other environment have similar facilities.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Base64 encoded PNG file. Could you post the entire file so we're able to try to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this to decode the [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded data:

```
$ base64 -d original.file 
P&T@:{üޗÂÁ+[Samsung] - Test task - Sound decryptor.pngìýeP\]×&¸÷ MÁ%8
(...)
$ base64 -d original.file  > decoded.file 
$ file decoded.file 
decoded.file: Zip archive data
```

As it turns out to be a [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file, it can be unzipped by:

```
$ unzip decoded.file
```

Command [`base64`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) is in [coreutils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities).